# Удалить из строки все нелегитивные символы

Tags: c++, c, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char s1[] = "бла-бла точка. запятая, циферки 12345613";
    cout << "строка до удаления нелитерных символов" << s1;

    for (i = 1, i < strlen(s1), i++) {
        if (isalpha(s1) == false,i--) {
            s1.erase(i, 1);
            cout << "строчечка после удаления нелитерных символов" << s1;
        }
        else
            cout << s1;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Удалить из строки все символы кроме букв, например «-«, «,»...

Comment: исправьте хотябы ошибки компиляции

Comment: Не могу , ты прочти как он предлагает их исправить ! , Да и сюда я пришел за помощью и не очень грамотно пишу программы

Comment: Поясните в чем состоит проблема?

Comment: @Cerbo не могу понять как удалить именно символы , цифры т е все кроме букв , не могу подобрать логичный и правильный алгоритм с определенным набором известных мне функций чар

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char s1[] = "wwqrqfwefg 556745 /\][' ";
    cout << "строка до удаления нелитерных символов" << s1 <<'\n';
    const int n = strlen(s1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(s1[i]))   //данная функция только для англ языка 
            s1[i] = ' ';
    }
   cout << "строчечка после удаления нелитерных символов" << s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if (!isalpha(s1[i])) - в этой строке ошибка

Comment: делайте сами, ладно? Вы сами не знаете что вам нужно

Comment: Удалить все кроме букв из строки

Comment: Вы о чем , ваша программа выдает ошибку в строке которую я указал выше!!!!!!!!!

Comment: нет там никакой ошибки, если вы включили нужные заголовочные файлы

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
Если нужны еще какие-нибудь , допишите пожалуйста , прошуу вас

Comment: #include <ctype.h>,  нужно еще

Comment: ваша реализация не удаляет, а заменяет "неалфавитный" символ на пробельный. Почему этот ответ засчитали правильным?

Comment: @Gromov Anton,  а вы попробуйте  написать так как нужно.  Те комментрии, в котором автор  указал, что ему нужны пробелы ставить, просто удалены

Answer (score 0):

Функция `get_alpha_array_from` возвращает динамически созданный массив `char`'ов, в котором нету "неалфавитных" символов.

Функция не заменяет т.н. "отвергнутый" символ на пробельный, а просто строит новую строку без ненужных нам символов, т.е. формально - это процесс их удаления.

Захотите - напишу больше комментариев.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_alpha_array_from ( char* buffer )
{
    size_t buffer_counter = 0;
    size_t buffer_length = strlen(buffer);

    char* alpha_array; 
    size_t alph_counter = 0;

    if ( NULL == buffer ) return NULL;

    alpha_array = (char*) malloc ( sizeof(char) *  ( buffer_length + 1) );
    if ( NULL == alpha_array ) return NULL;

    while ( buffer_counter < buffer_length )
    {
        if ( 0 != isalpha(buffer[buffer_counter]) )  /*если есть совпадение*/
        {
            alpha_array[alph_counter] = buffer[buffer_counter];
            alph_counter++;
        }

        buffer_counter++;
    }

    return alpha_array;
}

int main()
{
    char start_buffer[] = "I L2ov#e '(Sta3ckov]erfl)ow'";

    char* result_buffer = get_alpha_array_from( start_buffer );
    printf( "%s\n", result_buffer );
    /*что-то ещё делаем с полученной строкой*/
    if ( result_buffer ) free( result_buffer ); /*не забудьте освободить во всяком случае*/
    return 0;
}
```